# редирект на сайт в интернете при открытии хоста в wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

я пытаюсь настроить wamp и делать первый проект в нем. Проект доступен в сети, но редактирую в вампе его сорцы.
При открытии хоста в wamp или просто наборе в браузере: my.site (так настраиваю локально) происходит редирект на сам непосредственно сайт в интернете (пусть это допустим будет mysite.ru)

пробовал чистить ipconfig /flushdns не помогает.

файл хостс:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 my.site

::1 localhost
::1 my.site
```

файл апача:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.site
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/my-website/www"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp/www/my-website/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

сам вамп на ошибки не ругается, но при отрытии хоста ожидаю чтобы запрос шел на локальный айпи и порт но этого почему-то не происходит.

п.с файл index.php лежит в d:/wamp/www/my-website/www/

п.с2 нашел что в сорцах проекта лежит файл .htaccess с следующим содержимым:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Force non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^stage.mysite.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^stageng-mysite-subdomain.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
# Rewrite extensionless to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

удаление его, позволило открыть локально все страницы кроме главное. при наборе my.site/index.php я все еще получаю редирект на этот сайт в сети (mysite.ru)

пробовал перезагружать вамп, разворачивал на виртуалке - все воспроизводится. Где сидит этот редирект с главной - ума не приложу..

п.с3 - в самом индекс файле проекта его не наблюдаю - написан на топорном пхп, вручную, через инклюды и статику..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ответ - в проекте был файл .htaccess в котором были правила на редирект. И сам браузер также кеширует эти редиректы. При удалении этого файла и свежей ос и браузере - они не наблюдаются.